# Is it possible to configure the trackpad of a MBP in Windows alone (i.e. no BootCamp)?

Tags: keyboard, windows, touchpad

So, this is the thing, I have a Windows to Go device I would like to have configured to use with a 13-inch MacBook Pro from late 2013. I had no trouble getting the drivers for the different parts of the system using the Boot Camp package Apple provides and Windows Update itself.

But the problem is that the trackpad seems to be kind of useless. I mean, I can't even single tap much less tap with two fingers to right click (clicking with two fingers does seem to work though).

Looking around I saw that the Boot Camp app should allow me to configure the trackpad gestures as well as the keyboard special keys (e.g. increasing/decreasing the brightness of the screen, multimedia buttons, etc.), but that seems to apply to Boot Camp installations only, since every time I tried to open the settings of that app I get this error message stating that either I haven't got the right permissions (but I ran it through UAC, so the only thing above it is SYSTEM) or that it can't access some configuration drive or partition.

[image: Device manager showing drivers are installed, error message when trying to access Boot Camp control panel.]

Since it's a Windows to Go environment internal drives are not online by default, but it doesn't matter whether I bring it online or not; the same error pops up every time I try to open the Boot Camp control panel.

So I was wondering if anything can be done about this, if it's even possible to control the settings or at least get a minimum of comfort working in such an environment. Any ideas?

Most of the hardware here seems to be quite special regarding drivers (e.g. even if Broadcom is the manufacturer of a chip you need to get the driver from Apple), but I wonder if it'd be possible to force something like Microsoft's precision drivers on the trackpad and control the settings through the Windows' settings app itself.

P.S.: I posted it here hoping this is the right place among the StackExchange family but if you think it belongs in SuperUser or some other one please don't hesitate to move it mods and sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Windows to Go is essentially a Windows 10 "Live CD." I don't know much about it but you need to be able to install the drivers for the trackpad (I *think*) before it dumps you into Windows Explorer/Desktop. Which is really a Windows (Superuser) Question, like: "how do I install a third party driver in Windows To Go." or some such. You will find a few people with some Windows experience (like me) but the most expertise on Windows won't be here, usually.

Comment: I thought about it when posting the question @SteveChambers, but I figured this site would suit better in the end. I'm going to raise it up to the mods for them to decide though, although I think I may be out of luck for a solution. Anyway I think W2G is more like an installation of Linux in external media rather than a _Live CD_ like environment, but with all drivers properly installed and up to date it's just not productive to use it in a MacBook (Pro in this case), the inability to tap and double tap (and having to click instead) really decreases comfort when working in my case.

Answer (score 1):

This procedure MAY require you to have access to a Mac but basically all the Boot Camp drivers for the Mac are already packaged up nice and neat *inside* of the Boot Camp.app package.

If you download the [correct bootcamp](https://support.apple.com/downloads/boot-camp) for your Mac, you do not need to run it. Instead right-click on the Boot Camp.app and select "Show Package Contents...". It will open another window and inside that window (possibly at the first level but you may have to go through the folders there. Will be a .zip file. Those are the packaged Windows drivers. Copy them to your Mac with Windows and open it up and run the installers found within.

If you go to the URL above you *may* get **just the drivers you need** rather than the actual Boot Camp.app. I tried some of the downloads from a PC and I am getting the drivers rather then the Mac Boot Camp application package with the drivers inside. Which could make the process a whole lot simpler and allowing you to bypass the whole procedure above.

I'll leave them both in just in case.

But the Boot Camp Drivers are what you need and will set you up for trackpad usage.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! But I do have it all installed, drivers and Boot Camp app, I'll edit the questions with a screenshot of the message I get, which is probably because I'm running directly from an USB.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, my guess is the boot camp was not designed to WTG so it won't opened the control panel, even (startup disk permission) is not related to trackpad settings at all.

Comment: Welcome to Super User.  The intent is that answers be definitive solutions rather than speculation.  If you're guessing, research it and then post an answer.